# What is the Probability that $B,D,F,G$ will go to semi final

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

There are two groups of four players that is $A,B,C,D$ and $E,F,G,H$. Every one in a particular group plays a game with the one in same group. Given that $B$ always wins when he plays with $D$ and $F$ always wins when he plays with $H$. Assuming no Tie in this game Find probability that   $B,D,F,G$ will go to semi final

My try: since $B$ and $D$ are both in semifinal there will be no game with $B$ and $D$. So total games that are played in first group are $\binom{4}{2}-1=5$

Total games played in  second group is $6$.

Total number of cases is $5 \times 6=30$

How can we proceed with numerator

Comment: Does each player play one game against one other player in their group to determine who goes to the semifinals? Are the matchups within each group selected randomly? And besides for $B$ always beating $D$ and $F$ always beating $H$, are we assuming each game is $50/50$?

Answer (score 2):

For $B$ and $D$ to both reach the semifinals, they must not play each other in the first round of games. This has a $\frac23$ chance of happening (since $B$ can play $A$ or $C$ but not $D$).  If they are playing in separate games, the chances of $B$ and $D$ both winning their respective games and advancing to the semifinals is $\frac14$ (assuming that $B$ and $D$ each have a $50$% chance of beating $A$ or $C$).  Therefore, the probability of $B$ and $D$ both reaching the semifinals is $\frac 23\cdot\frac14=\frac16$

For the second group, we need to break down the first round matchup scenarios into three possibilities, each with probability $\frac13$ of occurring.

If $F$ and $G$ play each other in the first round, they can't both reach the semifinals.

If $F$ plays $E$ in the first round, there is a $\frac14$ chance of both $F$ and $G$ advancing.

If $F$ plays $H$ in the first round, $F$ will for sure win, so there is a $\frac12$ chance of $F$ and $G$ both advancing.

Overall, the probability of $F$ and $G$ both reaching the semifinals is $\frac13\cdot\frac14+\frac13\cdot\frac12=\frac14$

Since $B$ and $D$ reaching the semifinals and $F$ and $G$ reaching the semifinals are independent of each other, the probability of $B, D, F,$ and $G$ all reaching the semifinals is $\frac16\cdot\frac14=\frac1{24}$